# How can I use DOMTokenList directly?

Tags: javascript, html, prototype, domtokenlist

The short of this is that I want `HTMLElement.prototype.myList` to function like `HTMLElement.prototype.classList` or `.dataset`

I can't figure out how to instantiate a `DOMTokenList`, however.  I can get code to work against a polyfill (https://github.com/jwilsson/domtokenlist/blob/master/src/DOMTokenList.js), but not the native object.  Against native, everything I try gives me: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

```
var n = new DOMTokenList();  // illegal
new DOMTokenList({}, 'foo'); // illegal
```

or via prototypes, I get more illegal / not function errors.

So does anyone know how to use the native code to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `Object.create`?

Comment: @BenFortune -- Yes, same thing.  `var foo = Object.create(DOMTokenList.prototype); foo.add()`

Comment: Don't modify objects you don't own. Specially if they are host objects.

Comment: @Oriol -- Not helpful.

Comment: @BenFortune -- This question may have been asked, but "impossible" is not the appropriate answer, therefore can you please remove the dupe tag as I can answer it myself.

Comment: I've voted to re-open, considering the duplicate doesn't have an accepted answer.